# How can I make the regular expression not result in “catastrophic backtracking”?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I try to run below code in javascript, the browser hangs because of catastrophic backtracking which loops infinitely probably because of a poorly designed regular expression. I need either an alternative expression or a way to prevent this issue:

```
string temp = "Testing robustness {parent-area-identifier Some text in between the tokens {parent-area-label}";
var strRegExp = new RegExp(/[{](?:[^{}]+|[{][^{}]*[}])*[}]/g);
var arrMatch = temp.match(strRegExp);
```

Comment: And what it should do?

Comment: It shouldn't hang the browser and return proper results. I think in this case, it should match the "{parent-area-label}" and ignore the previous token.

Comment: texted on http://regexr.com/ and seem to work correctly.... update: checked with the example and timeout is reported

Comment: What is proper result?

Comment: in Regexr, On the top-right you'll see a small box which says 'timeout'. So it's basically sets a timeout period for that expression. That would work for me. How do I implement timeout?

Comment: I actually wanted to ignore the broken token and match others, however if that's something which cannot be done than I'd like what regexr did. Provide a timeout for the regex match and ignore everything if timeout period is reached.

Comment: No it says that the execution was too long and that it failed. Add expected result, so we can create you a valid RegExp

Comment: Expection Solutions:

1) It should match "{parent-area-label}" and ignore "{parent-area-identifier" (one which is not closed).

2) It should ignore everything and should NOT hang the browser.

Comment: You should start by not using the `RegExp` constructor when you already have a regex literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex looks like it's meant to match balanced braces that have more balanced pairs nested within, but only one level deep.  This regex does that without hanging on malformed input:

```
{[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*}
```

This is an example of [Jeffrey Friedl's](http://regex.info/book.html) unrolled loop technique.  When the first `[^{}]*` runs out of non-brace characters, the next part tries to match a simple, non-nested brace pair, then goes back to looking for non-braces.  That part is looped to allow for multiple nested brace pairs (but all at the same level).

This may appear even more vulnerable to catastrophic backtracking (nested quantifiers, everything optional) but it works because it never has to backtrack, even when no match is possible.

As an aside, you don't need to escape braces as long as it doesn't look like you're trying to use them as part of a quantifier.  (In some flavors you would need to escape the left brace, but not JavaScript.)

Also, if you want to match braces nested to an unknown depth, you're out of luck.  Some flavors can manage that, but JavaScript is way too limited.

Comment: Even if this construct is much better, it may cause a lot of "normal" (i.e: not catastrophic) backtracking, in particular when you add content at the end of the example string (see https://regex101.com/r/zW9nG6/1). You can prevent it using the atomic group emulation: https://regex101.com/r/zW9nG6/2

Comment: wow!! I think you NAILED it :)  Works perfectly, I'm still testing thoroughly before marking it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select an area without curly brackets, try to use this method:

```
var temp = "{=rankedArea?metricType=3902&area={parent-area-identifier}:AdministrativeWard} {=rankedArea?metricType=3902&area={parent-area-identifier}:{ward-type-identifier}} {district-short-label}  adfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf {child-area-short-label}  asdf asdf asdf  {authority-area-short-label} asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=compare?metricType=3343&greater=greater than&equal=equal to&less=less than}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=countAreas?area={ancestor-2-identifier}:{ancestor-1-type-identifier}}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=equivalent?metricDimension=[218][218_Number][Specificethnicity][Ethnicity_AsianorAsianBritish]}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf {=metricTypeMetadata?metricType=3341&returnValue=source}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=value?metricType=3284}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=percent?metricType=518}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=rank?metricType=3287}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf{=rankedArea?metricType=3286}  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdf";
var strRegExp = new RegExp(/{(?:[^{}]+|{[^{}]*})*}/g);
var arrMatch = temp.match(strRegExp);
console.log(arrMatch.length);
console.log(arrMatch);
```

Result:

```
13
["{=rankedArea?metricType=3902&area={parent-area-identifier}:AdministrativeWard}",
 "{=rankedArea?metricType=3902&area={parent-area-identifier}:{ward-type-identifier}}",
 "{district-short-label}",
 "{child-area-short-label}",
 "{authority-area-short-label}",
 "{=compare?metricType=3343&greater=greater than&equal=equal to&less=less than}",
 "{=countAreas?area={ancestor-2-identifier}:{ancestor-1-type-identifier}}",
 "{=equivalent?metricDimension=[218][218_Number][Specificethnicity][Ethnicity_AsianorAsianBritish]}",
 "{=metricTypeMetadata?metricType=3341&returnValue=source}", "{=value?metricType=3284}",
 "{=percent?metricType=518}",
 "{=rank?metricType=3287}",
 "{=rankedArea?metricType=3286}"]
```

It works fast, if this algorithm is incorrect, please provide more test cases.

Comment: I've nested tokens. Your pattern won't work in that case. Check out this: http://regexr.com/3co1m

Comment: Nishit, I have updated my solution, it should work now, your regular expression is fine, you should just a little bit modify it, please look at my solution, thanks.

Comment: Your regex is the same as the OP's now, and suffers the same problem when the input is malformed.  Test it by removing the second closing brace in your test string (the one after `:AdministrativeWard`); I get a catastrophic backtracking error in RegexBuddy.

Comment: It doesn't work on regexr. And yes, My regex too has the same problem